# Spring boot 2.1.7 having tomcat-embed-core conflit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am migrating existing Spring project into Spring boot.unable to run spring boot application its showing following error.

[image]

The error log says there is a conflict on tomcat-embed-core.
In eclipse Dependency hierarchy of porm.xml is given below
[image]

i  exclude the maven architect ,and try to run the application its showing following error

[image]

porm.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- 2.1.3.RELEASE -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <name>MyService</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
            <version>${jconn3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

what was wrong in this porm.xml

Comment: Could you also post your complete pom.xml or at least more, I don't see the spring-boot-import do you use the parent pom or the other way?

Comment: I think you do not need to import `tomcat-jdbc`, just import `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa``spring-boot-starter-test` is sufficient, Ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: am using spring-boot-maven-plugin

Comment: any specific reason to add `tomcat-juli` ?

Comment: or create dummy project from https://start.spring.io/, add all dependencies and compare the pom.xml with your project's pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Where is

${tomcat.version}

defined?

That version probably does not match the tomcat version that auto magically is included with spring boot items.

And thus the conflict.

Go here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.7.RELEASE

And start following the COMPILE dependencies, and you'll find the versions that are auto included with 2.1.7.RELEASE.  and you have to alter the other includes that are overwriting the springboot auto include tomcat versions.

Again, follow the COMPILED dependency trail.

---

So below is what you should find by crawling the COMPILED dependency trail (from immediately above in my answer)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.7.RELEASE

And you'll find you need to set

tomcat.version to

9.0.22

By defining tomcat.version as 8.x, you are breaking it.

---

Another way to put it

You have to go ~way~ back to springboot 1.5.2.RELEASE or 1.5.3.RELEASE

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.3.RELEASE

(Again, in the two above links, looked at the COMPILE dependencies)

To find a version of tomcat (that is auto included with springboot) that gets close to tomcat 8.5.x (where 8.5.x is the one you are attempting to use)

That's pretty old.

---

The principal you are missing is that springboot auto includes dependencies.  And anything else you import has to play nice with everything springboot auto includes.

And your current value for tomcat.version is NOT playing nice with everything springboot 2.1.7.RELEASE is auto including.

---

And now that you've been through all of that.  You'll find you'll make your life easier if you engage the springboot world more completely.

Alot of times, springboot will have a (sub)package that will bring in the thing you really desire.

spring-boot-starter-jdbc

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.7.RELEASE

You would probably be better off bringing that package in, vs hand-picking ones.  Aka, get rid of your "tomcat-jdbc" include and see if the spring-boot-starter-jdbc can give you what you want.

The curse/blessing of spring-boot is that it is its own universe.  But if you engage, you probably want to play by its rules more often than not.

---

PS

It is pom.xml, not porm.xml

Comment: <tomcat.version>8.5.12</tomcat.version>

Comment: I asked WHERE is it defined as well.  It's not in the POM.xml you posted.

Comment: that version is define in my parent porm.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove `tomcat-juli` and `tomcat-jdbc` dependencies. If you need JDBC support, add the corresponding starter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you use JSP views, you will probably need the following dependencies as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, pay attention to your dependencies versions. Spring Boot's parent POM defines version management for many common artifacts so you don't need to set the `<version></version>` for these libraries. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions